# automatic generation of DTO

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, maven, jpa, dto

I have a webservice that exposes hundreds of DTO that are derived from JPA entity.
Is it possible to automate the generation (**not the mapping**) of this DTO ?

Thanks.

Comment: Isoman: this is usually a bad idea, because you end up tying the internal representation of the problem (your model) to what your the users of your webservice care about. So a change on one side forces you to change the other side. If you still want to generate the DTOs you can write a bit of code that uses Java 6 annotation processors to create the DTOs.

Comment: what are the alternatives ?

Comment: One alternative would be to use the JPA entities directly, eg. as outlined in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14135708/687514). Otherwise I quite agree with @Augusto, the model your webservice users want might not be (or even rarely is) a 1:1 representation of your JPA model.

Comment: @isoman the alternative is to handcraft the DTOs in the way that a client might use them.