# How to use util.List in GWT RPC

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gwt-rpc

I have this situation:

### class User

```
@Entity
@Configurable(preConstruction=true)
public class User extends AbstractBussinessObject implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Warrior> warriors;
...
```

### class UserDto

```
public class UserDto extends AbstractDto implements Serializable{
    private List<WarriorDto> warriors;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public UserDto() {}

    public UserDto(Long id, List<WarriorDto> warriors, String name, String password) {
        this.warriors = warriors;
        ...
```

### class Warrior

```
@Entity
public class Warrior extends AbstractBussinessObject implements Serializable{
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    ...
```

### class WarriorDto

```
public class WarriorDto extends AbstractDto implements Serializable{
    private User user;
    ...
```

### method in WarriorServiceImpl

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<WarriorDto> getAllWarriors() {
    List<Warrior> wars = null;
    List<WarriorDto> warsDto = new ArrayList<WarriorDto>();
    try {
        wars = genericDao.getAll(Warrior.class);
        if (wars != null) {
            for (Warrior war : wars) {
                warsDto.add(createWarriorDto(war));
            }   
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return warsDto;
}
```

### method in DAO

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <ENTITY> List<ENTITY> getAll(Class<ENTITY> clazz) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(
    "SELECT e FROM " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " e")
    .getResultList();
}
```

### applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.platform}" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="cz.sutak.game" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Podpora deklarativni demarkace transakci - anotace @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" mode="aspectj" />

    <bean id="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="txManager" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

### complete code

https://github.com/sutakjakub/game

And if I want call `WarriorService.Util.getInstance().getAllWarriors(
                new AsyncCallback<List<WarriorDto>>()` in widgets it will failure with this message: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details.
In Jetty is only this message: [ERROR] 500 - POST /game/warrior (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes

No error message more.
Is problem in serialization (util.List)? Do u have some idea? 
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
This is error message in terminal (sorry i didnt look that):

ERROR LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: cz.sutak.game.client.bo.User.warriors, no session or session was closed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the client side Hibernate has no way of fetching the attributes you marked with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. You either need to fetch them eagerly on the server side og null the Hibernate proxies before passing the object graph over the wire.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135708/687514) in another thread for tips on nulling Hibernate proxies.

Cheers,

Comment: EAGER was helpful ... but still i have message _com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details. In Jetty is only this message: [ERROR] 500 - POST /game/warrior (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes_

Comment: You'll have to set breakpoints in the server and/or callback and debug from there, I'm afraid.

Comment: In the absence of eg. NPE's in your own code, I'm guessing that some object in your graph isn't `Serializable` (hibernate proxies aren't) and that causes you troubles with the GWT serializer classes. Try the approach I've linked to, or use eg. [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html) to map your domain objects.

Comment: Can you look on my code please? https://github.com/sutakjakub/game
I absolutely clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Here As you said there is nothing to do with `GWT`,because its server side code.Even on clien side  GWT supports `Util.List`.

And coming to the original problem.Its with the line    `wars = genericDao.getAll(Warrior.class);`

while accessing this line there is no `hibernate session` opened.

Comment: Im using Spring ORM. This is my applicationContext.xml: added top

Comment: Satus code 500 means,Some error occured in  serverside  while processing the RPC you requested from GWT.You can get the full stacktrace in Error logs

Comment: This is http://pastebin.com/R21A7P5E log after called  `WarriorService.Util.getInstance().getAllWarriors( new AsyncCallback<List<WarriorDto>>()`. I dont know why it dont function. My tests is ok. But in rpc call dont function

Comment: Ok..may be its an servlet path i am thinking now ..is it triggering your method ?

Comment: I dont know what does trigerring mean exactly. But the only one method that takes care of query is on the top this ask.

Comment: Yep, call going to server.

Comment: I did'nt see any exception there in paste bin