# Remove Proxy Code from Entity during Serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a server and clients that are both Java-based and communicate with each other over RMI. The server's data access layer is implemented with JPA and Hibernate and entities are often used as parameters.

The clients do not have Hibernate code and dynamic code download is disabled, so when the server sends an entity to its clients, the actual entity must be sent, not the proxy. Moreover, **the entity must be sent as-is, without pre-loading all lazy-fetched attributes because they will never be needed by the clients** in most cases.

Is it possible to implement these requirements with Hibernate?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object

Comment: @Korgen Thanks, but doesn't getHibernateLazyInitializer() pre-fetch all referenced entities?

Comment: from what I see from the API you'd have to call the initialize method to fetch them (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/proxy/LazyInitializer.html)

Comment: My [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14135708/687514) might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch all properties in the query

from docs

> If you are using property-level lazy fetching (with bytecode instrumentation), it is possible to force Hibernate to fetch the lazy properties in the first query immediately using fetch all properties.

```
from Document fetch all properties order by name
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

or use eagle fetch in your mapping...

Answer (score 0):

The only clean way I know of (that is without fetching every association for the object) is to use a separate object layer for data transportation.

Alternatively you can send the same object types repopulated by you with the necessary data, instead of hibernates objects with the proxies set.